# Principal agent problem with correlated output

Tags: game-theory, principal-agent

I am a bit confused by one question I am working on since some of the questions seem to suggest a differnt answer from the one I get in the earlier question. Here is the exercise and my working.

One principal and two agents, agent two being altruistic and for simplicity agent 2 receives no payment and always work for the principal.

Agents produce noisy and perfectly correlated output $x_i$ for $i=1,2$:

$$
x_i = e_i + \epsilon
$$

where $e_i$ is the effort level and $\epsilon$ is a r.v. with mean $E[\epsilon] = 0$ and variance $V[\epsilon]=1$.

Agent 1 receives the following payment

$$
\tau = a +bx_1 + Bx_2
$$

and maximizes the following risk averse utility

$$u_1 = E[\tau] -V[\tau]/2 -e_1^2/2$$

Agent 2 instead is risk neutral and altruistic according to $\gamma$

$$
u_2 = \gamma u_1 - e_1^2/2
$$

Principal maximizes profit

$$
\pi = E[x_1] + E[x_2] - E[\tau]
$$

Timing is: principal chooses $a,b,B$ and makes an offer. Agent 1 either accept or reject. If reject, all get zero. If accepts, then both agents choose effort level and production happens.

The game is solved by backward induction starting from the choices of effort, taking $a,b,B$ terms as given.

Let's compute

$$
E[\tau] = a +be_1 +Be_2
$$

and

$$
V[\tau] = (b+B)^2
$$

Agent two problem:

$$
\max u_2 = \gamma(a +be_1 +Be_2 - (b+B)^2 -e_1^2/2) - e_2^2/2 
$$

Taking the derivative in $e_2$ we get the FOC

$$
\gamma B -e_2 = 0
$$

so optimal effort $e_2 = \gamma B$. **Here the text of the question throws me, because it asks to derive $e_2$ as a function of both $b$ and $B$, but I only get it as a function of $B$. Am I missing something?**

Similarly, I get the effort for agent 1 is

$$
e_1 = b
$$.

The principal problem is solved with a trick and maximizing the function and replacing efforts with their optimal solutions before optimizing in $b,B$.

$$
\pi + u_1 = e_1 +e_2 - e_1/2
$$

Here I am supposed to get that $B^*=0$ but I get different results.